# convert an existing Lunar Lander program from C using SDL to the android phone

Tags: java, android, c, sdl, andengine

for a project we have to convert an existing Lunar Lander program from C using SDL to the android phone.... I dont even know where to begin. teacher didnt really help and there is nothing in my book that guides me on using sdl...any helpful tips or tutorial links?

http://penguin.ewu.edu/cscd439/android/Summer_12/cscd439_l5.html

Comment: I would recommend doing some research (e.g. on Google) first and then asking more specific questions on Stack Overflow. This type of broad question isn't really going to get many constructive answers.

Comment: ya what do you think ive been doing the past few days? i cant find any good tutorials or help. been google-ing all day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since SDL has an Android port, all you would need to do is cross-compile your game for the underlying hardware (typically ARM) and perhaps provide a simple Java-based lanucher..

You might want to have a look at what the [ScummVM](http://scummvm.org/) people have [done](https://sites.google.com/site/scummvmandroid/) for [their own port to Android](http://wiki.scummvm.org/index.php/Android/Guide). At worst, you could rip out most of the ScummVM code base and replace it with your own game to make a fast port to Android.

Answer (score 1):

This may help: http://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL/README.android